# Javascript Regex: nine or twelve digits in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

trying to use regex to validate that a string contains 9 or 12 digits (but not 10 or 11), currently using a list of two regexes and checking the input string twice. Can this be simplified?

```
var regexes = [/^[0-9]{9}$/, /^[0-9]{12}$/]
for (var i = 0; i < regexes.length; ++i) {
       if (regexes[i].test(input))
           return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
/^[0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?$/
```

So 9 digits, possibly followed by 3 more digits.

However, there is nothing wrong with checking two possibilities as you have.

Comment: You could also use `\d` which stands for a digit.

Comment: I would have thought checking two possibilities would affect performance?

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d{9}(\d{3})?$/
```

This should work :D

Answer (score 2):

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{9}$|^[0-9]{12}$/;
if (input.match(regex)!= null)
    return true;
```